# Disabling the continue button when there is no selection from the table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a list from backend. This list is displaying the user's invoices. I want the button to be disabled if the user doesn't select at least one invoice. If the user selects at least 1 invoice, I want the button to be active. But the invoices and the button are in different components.

**payment-table.js**

> Here the IDE warns me like this; **'setEnabledButton' is assigned a value but never used.**

```
  const [selectedItems, setSelectedItems] = useState([]);

  const [enabledButton, setEnabledButton] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (selectedItems.length > 0) {
      setEnabledButton = true;
    } else {
      setEnabledButton = false;
    }
  }, [selectedItems]);
```

**policy-payment-info.js**

```
<div className={hiddenControlButtonClass}>
  <AS.Button variant="outlined" onClick={handlePayment} enabledButton>
    {t('policy-payment-info.continue')}
  </AS.Button>
</div>
```

Comment: Where do you render your policy-payment-info.js component? Can you please provide that code as well.

Comment: Actually, I pass the list that comes to me to the table with props. The code is too long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set default state for your useState function :

```
  const [enabledButton, setEnabledButton] = useState(false);
```

After this you need to execute the seState by add `()`

Like this :

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (selectedItems.length > 0) {
      setEnabledButton(true);
    } else {
      setEnabledButton(false);
    }
  }, [selectedItems]);
```

And then, you need to use this state to enable or disable the button :

```
<div className={hiddenControlButtonClass}>
  <AS.Button variant="outlined" onClick={handlePayment} disabled={enabledButton}>
    {t('policy-payment-info.continue')}
  </AS.Button>
</div>
```

Comment: Since invoices and button are different components, I get a warning like this; 'enabledButton' is not defined. How do i pass button state to previous component?

Comment: The enabledButton state need to be use as prop inside AS.Button, can you add AS.Button component?

Comment: It's called ASLibrary. This is a component with icons.

Comment: So how do you want to use the state to disable the icon?
Where is your button component?

Comment: I solved the problem. I defined the state in the parent component. then I passed it to the table with props. Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is a little bit off. `setEnabledButton` is a function that has to be invoked and given the a certain value. Try this:

```
const [selectedItems, setSelectedItems] = useState([]);

  const [enabledButton, setEnabledButton] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (selectedItems.length > 0) {
      setEnabledButton(true);
    } else {
      setEnabledButton(false);
    }
  }, [selectedItems]);
```